# SQL: table left join return php array structure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, and I want to get data from table A to table B with a left join and table B will return many results for each record in table A
, 
I am already try to use group_concat and order_by to fetch results,
but it return results like that:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Harry
    [photos] => 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg
            ) 
[1] => Array(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Harry
    [photos] => 5.jpg,6.jpg
            )
)
```

BUT I hope the structure (PHP array) of results  as below:

Print results:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Harry
        [photos] => 
             Array(
                 [0] => 1.jpg
                 [1] => 2.jpg
                 [2] => 3.jpg
                 [3] => 4.jpg
                  )
                ) 
    [1] => Array(
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Harry
        [photos] => 
             Array(
                 [0] => 5.jpg
                 [1] => 6.jpg
                  )
                 )
     )
```

Table A:

```
---------------------
|  id  |  user_name | 
---------------------
|  1   |    Harry   | 
|  2   |    Peter   | 
---------------------
```

Table B:

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |   user_id  | photo_url | 
--------------------------------
|  1   |      1     |   1.jpg   | 
|  2   |      1     |   2.jpg   | 
|  3   |      1     |   3.jpg   | 
|  4   |      1     |   4.jpg   | 
|  5   |      2     |   5.jpg   | 
|  6   |      2     |   6.jpg   | 
--------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: the mysql results are never going to be a 2d array so you will have to post process the data no matter how it comes

Comment: I am try to use $result[$i]['photos'] = explode(",",$result[$i]['photos']); to get process data, it works but it not elegant. Do you have any better solutions? @Dagon

Comment: i dont know what elegant is, seems like a valid approach to me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use $result[$i]['photos'] = explode(",",$result[$i]['photos']); to get process data, it works but it not elegant.